# Django assertEqual does not show actual vs expected values

Tags: django, tdd, assertions

So I'm learning how to practice TDD in Django  and I'm having some minor trouble. I created a custom user object that links to authenticated system users in a one to one relationship. I have the following test, which exercises part of my custom user class:

```
def test_creating_a_user_with_attributes(self):
    myuser = Myuser.objects.create_user('Gary', email='me@email.com')
    current_time = now()
    myuser.birthday = current_time
    myuser.save()
    first_user = Myuser.objects.all()[0]
    self.assertEqual(first_user.birthday, current_time, 'first_user.birthday should be equal to the current_time')
```

The problem is that my test was failing and I couldn't immediately see why. The assert failure reported the message I had supplied and I was confused because I was certain that the birthday was set to the value of now. I ended up having to refactor my assert to make the failing value clear.

```
    self.assertEqual(first_user.birthday, current_time,
        'first_user.birthday ' + str(first_user.birthday) + ' should equal ' + str(current_time))
```

This revealed that the birthday was a date field and not a datetime field. My question is wether there exists some alternate form of assert that dumps the expected and actual values as part of the failure message or if I am somehow misusing or misunderstanding the API?

Comment: incidentally, have you taken a look at UserProfiles? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users  (apparently they're changing in Django 1.5 tho)

Comment: Thanx for the tip! I hadn't read all of the django docs yet. I'm trying to come up to speed using a number of tutorials and examples I'm finding around the internet and I'm reading "The Definitive Guide to Django 2nd edition"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django doesn't implement assertEqual, it simply uses Python's unittest module for that one.

What you need is to set the `longMessage` attribute to `True` for your test case class, like so:

```
class VerboseTestCase(TestCase):
    longMessage = True

    def test_creating_a_user_with_attributes(self):
        myuser = Myuser.objects.create_user('Gary', email='me@email.com')
        current_time = now()
        myuser.birthday = current_time
        myuser.save()
        first_user = Myuser.objects.all()[0]
        self.assertEqual(first_user.birthday, current_time, 'first_user.birthday should be equal to the current_time')
```

Which will output something like this if the test fails:

```
AssertionError: <datetime 1> != <datetime 2> : first_user.birthday should be equal to the current_time
```

This is explained in [Python's unittest docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.longMessage).

Answer (score 2):

The default error message *does* show the values that failed. But you have overridden that by supplying a third argument to `assertEqual`. If you left that out, it would print the values.

As Gonzalo shows, you can in fact get the best of both worlds by using the `longMessage` attribute.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I figured out the override shortly after posting and the longMessage attribute makes things even better.